# ORACLE not available

Tags: oracle11g, ora-01034, ora-27101

I installed Oracle 11g express edition on my windows7 OS.

But I got an error always.

My regedit.exe;

ORACLE_HOME : C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
ORACLE_SID : XE

and

My Environment Variables settings;

ORACLE_HOME : C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
ORACLE_SID : XE

And you see they are same.

I checked listener.ora file and same also in that file...

Finally start-> All programs-> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition -> start database I clicked.

After I checked the service;

OracleXETNSListener started,
OracleXEClrAgent started,
OracleServiceXE started.    And all of services log on Local System Account

And on cmd I got this error ... I dont know why :(

---

C:\Windows\system32>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Cmt May 12 16:17:51 2012
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYS
Enter password:

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Process ID: 0

Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Enter user-name: sys
Enter password:

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Process ID: 0

Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Enter user-name:

---

Pls help me..

I think my database cant not open. Yesterday ı done same things and I got this  error;

**ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0**

Also my : Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition  doesn't work. Always page not found.

Pls help me..